# Странное поведение linux: файлы под одним из пользователей создаются, но при записи в них содержимого удаляются

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, ftp

Ситуация такова. Есть `Debian 8`, недавно он был `Debian 7`. В нем есть один пользователь (не с правами root'а), при работе с которым возникают странные вещи. По `ssh` подключиться через него невозможно, хотя таковая возможность ранее была. Команда `su` также не помогает, консоль выглядит вот так:

```
15:05:23:root@server>~#su ouruser
Fri Mar 31 15:05:40 MSK 2017
15:05:40:root@server>~#
```

Лог `/var/log/auth.log` выглядит в этот момент так:

```
Mar 31 17:29:37 server su[2172]: Successful su for ouruser by root
Mar 31 17:29:37 server su[2172]: + /dev/pts/1 root:ouruser
Mar 31 17:29:37 server su[2172]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user ouruser by sshuser(uid=0)
Mar 31 17:29:37 server su[2172]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user ouruser
```

Где `sshuser` - это пользователь, под которым мы сначала попали на сервер по `ssh`, а потом уже при помощи `su -` попали под `root`, откуда и проводим эксперимент. Предупреждая вопросы - нет, из под `sshuser` тоже не получается попасть в нужного нам пользователя через `su -`.

При подключении через `ftp` коннект происходит, однако тоже есть странности - при попытке создания некоего файла он создается, однако при последующей попытке записать в этот файл что-либо он просто исчезает.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема или с чего начать диагностику? Пересоздание пользователя в целом вариант, но крайний, и рассматриваться будет последним.

Comment: А не руткит ли у вас?
PS, хотя достаточно и юзермодной заразы для такого поведения...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов на одном единственном пользователе? Я проверял через rkhunter, все чисто. Как считаете, его недостаточно, или стоит доверять?

Comment: Я бы попробовал подцепить диск к заведомо чистой машине и нормальным АВ еще пройтись...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов было бы здорово, если этот пользователь не находился на vps за тысячу километров от меня :)

Comment: Тогда печаль...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, ответ был найден [на другом сайте](https://toster.ru/q/412647). Вот та часть, которая интересует лично меня:

Это очень похоже на то, что вместо шелла у пользователя стоит /bin/date. Просто смените ему shell:

```
# chsh ouruser
Changing the login shell for ouruser
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
  Login Shell [/bin/date]: /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно файл создается с правами и/или группой другого пользователя и этот файл есть, но просто он от вас скрыт.

Comment: Да нет, смотрю из под рута, проверял таким образом - создавал файл - смотрел из под рута в консоли, файл есть (впрочем, его и в ftp-клиенте видно было), пробую через ftp-клиент записать в файл что-либо, файл в ftp-клиенте исчезает, из под рута в консоли даю на всю папку 777, опять смотрю через рута в консоли - пусто.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте другой ftp-клиент, или заливать уже заполненный содержимым файл.

Comment: Другой ftp-клиент пробовал, результат аналогичный. Пробовал заливать непустой файл - точно также удаляет. Собственно, я через другой клиент это и пробовал (PHPStorm), откуда и узнал про проблему.

Comment: Возможно на сервере лежит автозапускаемый файл, который удаляет. Если у вас удаленный сервер, то возможно что его владелец ограничил доступную вам память, то есть вы качаете файл и наполняете его, а память ограничена и файл автоматически удаляется. Попробуйте поудаляйте ненужные файлы, чтобы освободить память.

Comment: Тут дело в том, что изначально там был как раз тот файл, который я пытаюсь создать заново, просто после попытки записи в него он самоудалился. Так что версия интересная, но неверная - в любом случае, я пытаюсь записать во вновь создаваемый файл меньше информации, чем было в нем ранее (пару символов).

Comment: Попробуйте создать другой файл с другим именем и наполнить его. И проверьте удалится он или нет. Возможно дело в самом файле, может он какойто системный и содержит конфигурацию, и при запуске какогото процесса этот файл проверяется и очищается из-за неправильного содержимого.

Comment: Пробовал, естественно.